# Appium - Instruments crashed on startup Emulator

Tags: java, ios, xcode, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm new to appium, and I'm trying to run an example using the following code with Java / Intellij

OSX El Capitan 10.11.2
Appium version 1.4.16

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.2");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "http://appium.s3.amazonaws.com/TestApp6.0.app.zip");

driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

but I'm getting the following error

Here is the log info

```
  info: [debug] [INST] Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 20.832968s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)
    info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 0
    info: [debug] Killall instruments
    info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
    info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
    info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:22 Moisess-MacBook-Pro DTServiceHub[56640]: Could not create service named com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol.posixspawn
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:23 Moisess-MacBook-Pro assertiond[56635]: assertion failed: 15C50 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:23 Moisess-MacBook-Pro ScriptAgent[56697]: Warning - Unable to stop script because the script was already stopped.

    info: Launching instruments

    info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPhone 6 (9.2)

    info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 6 (9.2)" /var/folders/mj/ysvr7x097ynb626pxp6f2zbm0000gn/T/11605-56384-6yj58r/TestApp.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/moisessiles/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
    info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
    info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:28 Moisess-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[56630]: Weekly asset update check did fire (force=NO)

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:28 Moisess-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[56630]: Beginning check for asset updates (force: 0
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:28 Moisess-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[56630]: Did not complete check for asset updates (force: 0, isVoiceOverRunning: 0

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:29 Moisess-MacBook-Pro assertiond[56635]: assertion failed: 15C50 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:29 Moisess-MacBook-Pro DTServiceHub[56640]: DTMemlimitAssertionFactory: failed to remove active and inactive memory limits for pid 56707 (result = -1)

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:29 Moisess-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.5D6F2EC4-53A3-41E2-BCA6-108B991591C7.launchd_sim[56614] (UIKitApplication:D.TestApp[0xf0ea][56707]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:29 Moisess-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[56630]: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 56707: No such process
    info: [debug] [INST] 2016-01-05 22:14:29 +0000 Fail: The target application appears to have died
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:30 Moisess-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[56630]: Application 'UIKitApplication:D.TestApp[0xf0ea]' crashed.
    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:30 Moisess-MacBook-Pro assertiond[56635]: assertion failed: 15C50 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1
    info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-01-05 16:14:30.057 instruments[56702:7555272] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage

    info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Jan  5 16:14:30 Moisess-MacBook-Pro ScriptAgent[56708]: Warning - Unable to stop script because the script was already stopped.

    info: [debug] [INST] Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 1.587851s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)
```

I tried with a previous version of iphone and iOS and I'm getting this

```
warn: Applications directory /Users/moisessiles/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5D6F2EC4-53A3-41E2-BCA6-108B991591C7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application doesn't exist. Have you run this simulator before?
info: Couldn't find app directories to delete. Probably it's not installed
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup
    at [object Object].Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:440:31)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:353:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 147478.284 ms - 182
```

Comment: i know this could be late, but 1. Are you able to access the instruments in ways other than appium script? 2. Also please make sure you have Use `Native Instruments Library` checked under Advance settings for IOS platform in Appium's UI. 3. `Enable UI Automation` setting in setting--developer

Answer (score 2):

What is the version of xcode you are using? As you are using the IOS 9.2 you need to upgrade Xcode and instruments.
i had successfully resolved same issue by upgaring my OS, xcode and instruments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using XCode version 7.2 (7C68) and Instruments Version 7.2 (7C68), but the issue still there.

Comment: It seems you have some other issue with respect to the configuration/application as in logs i can see the error "Application 'UIKitApplication:D.TestApp[0xf0ea]' crashed." which i believe is related to your test application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Configure an Android Application on your Mac if it works fine the problem isn't from the version you use.
Else try to update the latest version of Xcode

Comment: I'm using XCode version 7.2 (7C68) and Instruments Version 7.2 (7C68), but the issue still there. I think I'm using the latest version of XCode.

Comment: First I'm trying with iphone, because the app on this example is for iOS 
http://appium.s3.amazonaws.com/TestApp6.0.app.zip

Comment: Ahh ok. because in my example it works fine with Android and in IOS there still some problems of compatibility between .ipa to .app (in app path it didn't detect my app correctly it opens than closed immediately)

Comment: thats my issue, it opens and then is closed. Do you have some android example? What I trying to do is to create some examples with iOS and Android using appium. I already have the Safari example done.

Comment: Sorry the app i'm testing is an internal project not available in playstore, but in Android it works fine on Mac OS. I'm using recorder with Android in order to automize my scripts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99957/discussion-between-emna-and-msiles).